# Hide zero value in stacked chart - SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have seen similar things asked after googling for a bit, but i am still have a few issues with hiding zero  values in a stacked bar chart in SSRS.

I have a stacked bar chart, and some of the stacked values will display the data label for zero values, which makes the label next to it hard to read. I am attempting to hide these zero values so only non zero labels are displayed.

I have found basically where i need to modify the properties to accomplish this, but the syntax of the expression is the part where i am having difficulties. I have added a field to series group in the chart data. I click on the fields in the chart to access the properties. in the chart series property, under the label section, i go to the visible property. I select expression. The problem i have is that i am unsure of what to put into the expression exactly. I have the following expression so far:

```
    =IIf(Count(Fields!Status)<>0, true, false)
```

The stacked bar chart shows the number of support tickets handled by each person, and the series group breaks it down further by current status of the tickets. Hiding the zero values seems like it would be fairly straight forward if it wasnt a stacked bar chart with a series group, but I am not sure how to access the series group values in the expression.

any advice on how to access the individual series group values in the expression?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer our through some trial and error and google. I had left out one important piece in the expression:

```
   =IIf(count(fields!Status.Value) = 0, false, true)
```

I left out the value attribute from status, which solved the problem. I found this value in the chart series properties, under datapoint - > values. It was the only value there, next to the Y property.

Comment: For me the problem was that `Visibility` points to the `Hidden` Property, so swapping the True and False's resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I thin the best way to hide zeroes is:

1) Right click on "Series label Properties"
2) Click on number
3) Decimal places  = 0
4) Flag "Show zero as:" and select  " " (there are 3 options" nothing (blank), "-" or "None"

I hope this help

Comment: This might not be the accepted answer but this is the only thing that would work for me, thank you!